# Bootstrap 4 centered logo and tagline on nav collapse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a Bootstrap 4 project where I have a nav bar with a centered logo and tagline, then some links to the left and right. It works pretty much as I would like, only ideally I would like the logo to stay centered after the nav links collapse.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white justify-content-between">
    <div class="container-fluid ">

        <div class="d-flex flex-column text-center order-lg-2">

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="">
            </a>    

            <h2 class="tagline navbar-text">eco freindly clothing</h2>

        </div>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".dual-nav">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse dual-nav w-50 order-lg-3">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">our ethics</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">contact</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">shop</a>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse dual-nav w-50 order-lg-1">

            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">instagram</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">facebook</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">pinterest</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>
</nav>
```

Currently after the links collapse the navbar toggle is on the right and logo and tagline on the left. How can I retain the logo and tagline in the center?

Here is a [codeply](https://www.codeply.com/go/lHyvfrkEbq)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `flexbox` parent of the brand, logo, navbar toggler and 2 collapsable menus is `.container-fluid`, not the `<nav>`. So you need to do `flex-direction: column;` on small screens and `flex-direction: row;` with `justify-content: space-between;` on larger screens.

You can use bootstrap built-in classes for that too.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white">
    <div class="container-fluid flex-column flex-lg-row justify-content-lg-between">
        ...
    </div>
</nav>
```

**fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/144985/ (don't want to register with codeply)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, makes sense and works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this really simply by creating a "centered" class for the div containing your logo and header text.

```
.centered {
margin:auto;
display:block;
}
```

Is this what you had in mind? See the codepen below.

https://www.codeply.com/go/nss8DJRYN3

Comment: Thanks for your response! This solution also works just perfectly. I think we can also use the Bootstrap class mx-auto instead of a custom one :)